# Query by date with column that is a datetime

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

How can I query for all records of a certain date if the column is a datetime?

This doesn't work. Is there a preferred way to do this in sequelize?

`startDate` and `endDate` are `datetime`'s

```
Thing.findAll({
  where: {
    startDate = {
      [Op.gte]: '02-20-2020'
    },
    endDate = {
      [Op.lte]: '02-20-2020'
    },
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split them and create a javascript Date object before using that straight in the query parameters.

```js
const [month, day, year] = '02-20-2020'.split('-')
const date = new Date(year, month, day)

Thing.findAll({
  where: {
    startDate = {
      [Op.gte]: date
    }
  }
});
```

See [Several ways to create a Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: But I also need to specify an end date b/c In my case I want to get data for a single day.

Comment: Just do the same thing again with the split and then the new date